# Android: Using Microphone and Headphones Simultaneously

Tags: java, android, audio

I have an application that needs to use a high-quality microphone and headphones simultaneously. On my phone, there is only one input for an audio device. How can I connect to and handle in/out data from each?

edit: I dont want to capture two input sources at once. I want to record from a microphone, use it to modify audio which i have already recorded, then output the result to a headphone in real time. I know this is possible, however I dont know how to connect and differentiate between two devices connected to the audio jack via a splitter.

Answer (score 1):

Most (probably all) Android devices with a 3.5mm port support a TRRS connector(https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)#TRRS_standards)

So there is a different hardware channel for the microphone and the headphones, and it's not possible to accidentally use the wrong one in software or for that matter manually select what to use the hardware connections for, it's predefined.

But so the point is that you need the right splitter exactly for this, not just a normal audio-splitter but one that specifically splits the input/microphone channel from the output/heaphone channel.

If you use the search term "audio and microphone 3.5mm splitter android", then you should find the correct splitter hardware shopping recommendations:

https://www.google.com/search?q=audio+and+microphone+3.5mm+splitter+android&tbm=shop

Here is an example picture:

[image: audio microphone splitter 3.5mm]